# Compiling error with Facebook flow using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

Tags: ocaml

When compiling [facebook flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow), with Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, I get an error. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/flow-0.18.1$ make
mkdir -p bin
tar czf bin/flowlib.tar.gz -C lib .
echo "const char* const BuildInfo_kRevision = \"$(git rev-parse HEAD 2>/dev/null || hg identify -i)\";" > hack/utils/get_build_id.gen.c
abort: there is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)
ocamlbuild -ocamlc "ocamlopt   -ccopt -DNO_LZ4"\
        hack/third-party/inotify/inotify_stubs.o hack/heap/hh_shared.o hack/hhi/hhi_elf.o hack/utils/files.o hack/utils/get_build_id.gen.o hack/utils/get_build_id.o hack/utils/handle_stubs.o hack/utils/nproc.o hack/utils/realpath.o hack/utils/sysinfo.o src/embedded/flowlib_elf.o
+ ocamlopt   -ccopt -DNO_LZ4 -c hack/hhi/hhi_elf.c
hack/hhi/hhi_elf.c: In function ‘get_embedded_hhi_data’:
hack/hhi/hhi_elf.c:116:3: warning: ‘elf_getshstrndx’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libelf.h:260) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   int stat = elf_getshstrndx(e, &shstrndx);
   ^
+ ocamlopt   -ccopt -DNO_LZ4 -c src/embedded/flowlib_elf.c
src/embedded/flowlib_elf.c: In function ‘get_embedded_flowlib_data’:
src/embedded/flowlib_elf.c:65:3: warning: ‘elf_getshstrndx’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libelf.h:260) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   int stat = elf_getshstrndx(e, &shstrndx);
   ^

Finished, 22 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:01.
ocamlbuild  -no-links  -I src/commands -I src/common -I src/dts -I src/embedded -I src/parser -I src/parsing -I src/server -I src/stubs -I src/typing -I hack/deps -I hack/dfind -I hack/find -I hack/globals -I hack/heap -I hack/parsing -I hack/procs -I hack/search -I hack/socket -I hack/stubs -I hack/third-party/avl -I hack/third-party/core -I hack/utils -I hack/third-party/inotify -I hack/fsnotify_linux -lib unix -lib str -lflags "hack/third-party/inotify/inotify_stubs.o hack/heap/hh_shared.o hack/hhi/hhi_elf.o hack/utils/files.o hack/utils/get_build_id.gen.o hack/utils/get_build_id.o hack/utils/handle_stubs.o hack/utils/nproc.o hack/utils/realpath.o hack/utils/sysinfo.o src/embedded/flowlib_elf.o -cclib -l -cclib elf   " src/flow.native
```

Here's the error:

```
+ /usr/bin/ocamlc -c -w A -warn-error A -w -27-32-34-45 -w -4-6-29-35-44-48-50 -I src/server -I hack/find -I hack/procs -I hack/fsnotify_linux -I hack/heap -I hack/deps -I hack/globals -I hack/dfind -I hack/parsing -I hack/stubs -I hack/search -I hack/utils -I hack/socket -I hack/third-party/inotify -I hack/third-party/avl -I hack/third-party/core -I src/commands -I src/dts -I src/typing -I src/parsing -I src/stubs -I src/common -I src/parser -I src/embedded -o src/server/autocompleteService_js.cmo src/server/autocompleteService_js.ml
```

And specifics:

```
File "src/server/autocompleteService_js.ml", line 128, characters 14-29:
Error: Unbound value Debug.json_of_t
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 114 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:05.
make: *** [build-flow] Error 10
```

Comment: @william007 have you tried installing via `opam`? `opam install flowtype`

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Nope, as part of my purpose is to play with source

Comment: opam can do that too for you, `opam source flowtype`